# QString str1 = "Test"; does not work

Tags: qt

studing sddm code from official git (https://github.com/sddm/sddm), I try to add this test code:

```
void UserModel::test() {
    QString str1 = "Test";
    qWarning("%s",str1);
}
```

but I have an error:

> whithin this context.

what does it mean?
how should I do to intialise a new QString variable?

Comment: Use qWarning() << str1;

Answer (score 0):

You're not posting the complete error, and you can't pass a `QString` directly to `qWarning`. To use the C format string, you need to convert it to the local encoding and pass a `const char*` to that, or better yet use the debug stream:

```
void UserModel::test() {
    auto str1 = QStringLiteral("Test");
    // preferred
    qWarning() << str1;
    // acceptable
    qWarning("%s", str1.toLocal8Bit().constData());
}
```